# How to change Product variaction images URL dynamicaly

Tags: php, woocommerce, product, product-variations

I want to change all product variactions images by custom URL. Is this possible?

```
function custom_change_variation_image_urls( $variation_data, $product, $variation ) {
    $custom_image_urls = array(
        'red' => 'https://example.com/red-image.jpg',
        'blue' => 'https://example.com/blue-image.jpg',
    );
    $variation_attributes = $variation->get_variation_attributes();
    if ( ! empty( $variation_attributes ) ) {
        foreach ( $variation_attributes as $attribute_name => $attribute_value ) {
            if ( isset( $custom_image_urls[ $attribute_value ] ) ) {
                $variation_data['image']['thumb_src'] = $custom_image_urls[ $attribute_value ];
                $variation_data['image']['src'] = $custom_image_urls[ $attribute_value ];
            }
        }
    }

    return $variation_data;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'custom_change_variation_image_urls', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Please provide some more details e.g. what result you are getting and what you were expecting. Please see this link for guide lines to ask a good question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask